# C Valgrind Conditional jump or move

Tags: c, valgrind

as the title suggests i have a problem with Valgrind where i get some errors that variables are uninitialised.
Here is what i wrote so far:

```
int login(char* input, int input_length){
//input = base64encoded user:pass
//decode data
//find username
//find pass
//hash pass
SHA1_CTX context;
uint8_t digest[20];
char* passlocation = NULL;
char* decoded = NULL;
char* username = NULL;
char* pass = NULL;
int temp = 0;
int login_status = -1;
int i = 0;
decoded = NULL;

if(input != NULL) {
    decoded = base64_decode(input, input_length);
}
if(decoded == NULL){
    return -1;
}
passlocation = strchr(decoded, ':'); //First Uninitalised error
if(passlocation) {
    temp = strlen(input) - strlen(passlocation);
}
if(temp == 0 || temp == (input_length-1)){
    return -1;
}
username = calloc(temp+1, sizeof(char));
strncpy(username, decoded, temp); //Second Uninitalised error
pass = calloc((input_length - temp), sizeof(char)); //Third Uninitalised error

strcpy(pass, (passlocation+1)); //inavlid read of size 1

if(username != NULL && pass != NULL){
    printf("Username: %s\n", username); //Fourth Uninitalised error
    printf("Password: %s\n", pass); //Invalid read of size 1
}


SHA1_Init(&context);
SHA1_Update(&context, (uint8_t *) pass, strlen(pass)); //invalid read of size 1
SHA1_Final(&context, digest);


login_status = identify_user(username, temp,(char*) digest);
clean_free(username);
clean_free(pass);
clean_free(decoded);
printf("%d\n",login_status);
return login_status;
```

}

I don't expect any of you guys to fix all my mistakes at once, i'd just like to understand why i get the first uninitialised error from valgrind since i have been trying to fix it for a mere 30hours(minus sleep) and i just don't see what my mistake is.

Thank you guys in advance!

Edit:
base64_decode:

```
char* base64_decode(char* toDecode, int toDecode_length){
static char encoding_table[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H',
                                'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
                                'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X',
                                'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
                                'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
                                'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
                                'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3',
                                '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '/'};
char* i=toDecode;
char* decoded = calloc(256,sizeof(char));
int octets[24];
int s=6;
int sc=0;
int c=0;
int n=0;
int threechars=0;
int threecharC=0;
int decodeC;
int deLoop;
int expo=1;
int aValue;
char temp;
while(c<(toDecode_length)){                                                 //länge des toDecode
        n=0;
    if(toDecode[c]!='='){
        while(toDecode[c]!=encoding_table[n]){                              //base64 char Wert ermitteln
            n++;
        }
        for(sc=1;sc<7;sc++){                                                //base64 char Wert in binär
            octets[s-sc]=n%2;
            n=n/2;

        }
        for(sc=0;sc<6;sc++){                                                //Ausgabe des Binärwertes in Konsole (Debug)
            //printf("%d",octets[s-6+sc]);
        }
    }else{
        for(sc=1;sc<7;sc++){                                                //bei base64 wert '=' mit 0 füllen
            octets[s-sc]=0;
            }
    }
        s=s+6;
        i++;
        threechars++;
    if(threechars==4){                                                      //ermitteln des ascii wertes und schreiben in decoded
        for(deLoop=8;deLoop<=24;deLoop=deLoop+8){
            for(decodeC=1;decodeC<=8;decodeC++){
                if(octets[deLoop-decodeC]==1){
                    aValue=aValue+expo;
                }
                expo=expo*2;
            }
            temp=aValue;
            decoded[threecharC]=temp;
            expo=1;
            aValue=0;
            threecharC++;
        }
    threechars=0;
    s=6;
    }
    c++;

}
//printf("return value %d",n);
return decoded;
```

}

```
Valgrind-log(via Command-line not Eclipse Plug-in)
==4383== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)  
==4383==    at 0x4C2DB9A: __GI_strchr (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-  amd64-linux.so)  
==4383==    by 0x401889: login (http-login.c:174)  
==4383==    by 0x4036DD: main_loop (http-server.c:140)  
==4383==    by 0x403902: main (http-server.c:214)  
==4383==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation  
==4383==    at 0x401568: base64_decode (http-login.c:81)  
==4383==   
==4383== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)  
==4383==    at 0x4C2DBA0: __GI_strchr (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)  
==4383==    by 0x401889: login (http-login.c:174)  
==4383==    by 0x4036DD: main_loop (http-server.c:140)  
==4383==    by 0x403902: main (http-server.c:214)
==4383==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation  
==4383==    at 0x401568: base64_decode (http-login.c:81)  
==4383==   
==4383== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)  
==4383==    at 0x4C2E78E: __strncpy_sse2_unaligned (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)  
==4383==    by 0x401929: login (http-login.c:182)  
==4383==    by 0x4036DD: main_loop (http-server.c:140)  
==4383==    by 0x403902: main (http-server.c:214)  
==4383==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation  
==4383==    at 0x401568: base64_decode (http-login.c:81)  
==4383==   
==4383== Invalid write of size 1  
==4383==    at 0x4C2E1F3: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)  
==4383==    by 0x40196C: login (http-login.c:185)  
==4383==    by 0x4036DD: main_loop (http-server.c:140)  
==4383==    by 0x403902: main (http-server.c:214)  
==4383==  Address 0x51fcf88 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd  
==4383==    at 0x4C2CC70: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)  
==4383==    by 0x401948: login (http-login.c:183)  
==4383==    by 0x4036DD: main_loop (http-server.c:140)  
==4383==    by 0x403902: main (http-server.c:214)
```

This is not a full log, if you want the full log i'll post it

Comment: Can you post your valgrind output?

Comment: And this function: base64_decode

Comment: I edited the things you asked for, if anything else is missing please let me know

Comment: Which line is line 81 at http-login.c? I would guess this if `if(octets[deLoop-decodeC]==1)`.

Comment: char* base64_decode(char* toDecode, int toDecode_length){  this is the line 81, so the start of the implementation of base64_decode

Comment: but the memory allocation is done with calloc which, as per definition, initialises the memory with 0-bytes aka '\0', so anything written into it will always be followed by a '\0' or am i wrong?

Comment: What happens if the `toDecode` parameter is larger than 256 characters?

Comment: the function doesn't work i guess, but i did not write that function so it is not my point to fix anything(we are working in a 4man team). i will forward your concerns to him!

Comment: Does anyone have a clue where i make a mistake that i myself don't see?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if ( !input ) return -1; decoded = base64_decode(input, input_length);` instead of `if(input != NULL) {...`? As it is now, if `input` is `NULL`, `decoded` stays uninitialized. What is the purpose of `i` in `base64_decode`?

Answer (score 0):

Your using pointers like storage. eg

```
char* passlocation = NULL;
```

Says, create a pointer that points to nowhere. Hence the Uninitalised errors when you try and use this pointer.

What you need to do is allocated memory for the data you want to store at the pointers location. eg

```
char* passlocation;
passlocation = (char *)malloc( 50 * sizeof(char) );
```

Then you'll be able to do meaningful operations on them (assuming your data is going to be lots than 50 chars. Don't forget to free the data after your done.

Comment: This is incorrect. `char* passlocation = NULL;` is actually initialised and is not the command that causes the warning.

Comment: It's not the command that creates the error, but it's the cause of the error. Fix this and the error will go away. (answer clarified)

Comment: Also i do get a memory leak as soon as i allocate memory for passlocation since i use strchr which will give me a pointer to my decoded pointer thus i can not free passlocation anymore.

Comment: That is a separate question!

Comment: just so you know it, what you said might or might not be true, but your code snipped doesn't resolve any problem. i still get conditional jump errors at exactly the same lines plus i then have a memory leak. i know you are more capable than me when it comes to coding and i am grateful for your help, but this doesn't net me anything.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the bug has been found!

Thanks for everyone that tried to help, it was much appreciated!!!

The problem, although valgrind marks it only in my function(aka login), was a result of an uninitialised value in base64_decode.

```
char* base64_decode(char* toDecode, int toDecode_length){
static char encoding_table[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H',
                            'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
                            'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X',
                            'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
                            'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
                            'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
                            'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3',
                            '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '/'};
char* i=toDecode;
char* decoded = calloc(256,sizeof(char));
int octets[24];
int s=6;
int sc=0;
int c=0;
int n=0;
int threechars=0;
int threecharC=0;
int decodeC;
int deLoop;
int expo=1;
int aValue = 0; //HERE WAS THE PROBLEM, uninitialised value!
char temp;
while(c<(toDecode_length)){                                                 //länge des toDecode
    n=0;
if(toDecode[c]!='='){
    while(toDecode[c]!=encoding_table[n]){                              //base64 char Wert ermitteln
        n++;
    }
    for(sc=1;sc<7;sc++){                                                //base64 char Wert in binär
        octets[s-sc]=n%2;
        n=n/2;

    }
    for(sc=0;sc<6;sc++){                                                //Ausgabe des Binärwertes in Konsole (Debug)
        //printf("%d",octets[s-6+sc]);
    }
}else{
    for(sc=1;sc<7;sc++){                                                //bei base64 wert '=' mit 0 füllen
        octets[s-sc]=0;
        }
}
    s=s+6;
    i++;
    threechars++;
if(threechars==4){                                                      //ermitteln des ascii wertes und schreiben in decoded
    for(deLoop=8;deLoop<=24;deLoop=deLoop+8){
        for(decodeC=1;decodeC<=8;decodeC++){
            if(octets[deLoop-decodeC]==1){
                aValue=aValue+expo;
            }
            expo=expo*2;
        }
        temp=aValue;
        decoded[threecharC]=temp;
        expo=1;
        aValue=0;
        threecharC++;
    }
threechars=0;
s=6;
}
c++;

}
//printf("return value %d",n);
return decoded;
}
```

Have a great evening everybody!